# Sending Email from Android app when click on button

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I need to provide feature for users where users can share some data by sending email. I used below code.

```
    Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,"Choose an Email client :"));
```

This shows Email, gmail, Skype and send via bluetooth for user to choose. I dont want user to show Skype,send via bluetooth in this list. What i need to do ? I have WhatsApp in my phone, which does same thing, but doesn't show Email, bluetooth in the list(Settings->help->Contactus->...).only show Email and Gmail in list. I need to do the same.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","email@email.com", null));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

If you don't have a specific recipient - go like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", "", null));
```

Comment: i check it. i want only mail client(gmail, yahoo, outlook) in list not Skype,send via bluetooth.what i do..?

Comment: @Amardeep Edited my answer. However, WhatsApp still uses custom dialog which shows only 2 email client in the list (Gmail and Email) even you have more than 2 email clients.

Comment: its not working in actual device. can i used this email.setType("message/rfc822");

Comment: @Amardeep Any error or what? It works for me on Samsung Galaxy Note Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to share via gmail only jus you need to call

```
startActivity(getSendEmailIntent(context, email,subject, body));





public Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email,
                    String subject, String body) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            try {

                // Explicitly only use Gmail to send
                emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
                        "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

                emailIntent.setType("text/html");

                // Add the recipients
                if (email != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { email });

                if (subject != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            subject);

                if (body != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));

                // Add the attachment by specifying a reference to our custom
                // ContentProvider
                // and the specific file of interest
                // emailIntent.putExtra(
                // Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                // Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/"
                // + fileName));

                 return emailIntent;
    //          myContext.startActivity(emailIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");

                // Add the recipients
                if (email != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { email });

                if (subject != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            subject);

                if (body != null)
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));

    //          myContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
    //                  "Share Via"));
                 return emailIntent;
            }
            }
```